# Count the number of pairs in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['a', 'b'],
    data={
        'a' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        'b' : [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
    }
)
```

How can I add a column named `c` containing number of same pairs of `a` and `b` in `df`:

```
c = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
```

Pair `a=1` `b=1` is present 1 time, `a=1` `b=2` two times, `a=2` `b=1` one time, `a=3` `b=4` three times and so on.

Comment: Can you please clarify:   "a=1 b=2 two times, a=2 b=1 one time," ..? what is the "number of same pairs"?

Comment: use: `df.groupby(['a','b'])['b'].transform('count')`

Comment: @anky_91 thanks a lot, it solves my question!